# How can I get the key value pair from Map in android

Tags: java, android, json, object

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject fees_history) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    int j = 0;
    Iterator<String> keysItr = fees_history.keys();
    while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next().toString();
        Object value = fees_history.get(key);
        if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            //How can i get the String value from this Object here
            //here i am logging
            Log.e("Value",value.toString());
            Unpaid_fees_detail_adapter unpaid_fees_detail_adapter = new Unpaid_fees_detail_adapter(ReportActivity.this, unpaid_fees_details);
            listView.setAdapter(unpaid_fees_detail_adapter);
        }
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

*Here is My value of Object which in am getting*

```
{date=29-07-2017,Reciept=RC1, Amount=11800}
```

I have commented there and my question is
how can I get the key value pair inside the Object.

I have tried a
lot of way by using `map.get(Object)` but I am failed to do it.I just
want how can I get the separate value of `date,Receipt,Amount`

Comment: Have you tried this `value.getString("Reciept");` ?

Comment: Have tried but giving error map cannot be conveted into object

Comment: you defined value as Object, and the toMap() method returns a Map. So value should be declared as a Map.

Comment: I don't understand why you convert value to Map, but since it is a Map you should do `value.get("Reciept");`

Comment: then how can i process any help

Comment: See You all cannot leave me alone i need a help from you friend please

Comment: you cannot simple use a hashmap to save a json without even recursively iterating over the json. Use gson or similar library to parse the json and access the data individually. rest of the work do it on your own, a bit of research and implementation. If you get stuck in your implementation then ask a question.

Comment: You can check my answer.@Sushil

Comment: You can try it.@Sushil

Comment: I can try but getting to much json object

Comment: here is my teamViewer Id:557 783 221 and pass is 6082 get connected with  me

Comment: What is getting to much json object? Just two `JSONObject` in the code .@Sushil

Comment: can i provide you api

Comment: thats why i telling i have provided my remote acess if you have time then connect to me @KeLiuyue

Comment: thats why i telling i have provided my remote acess if you have time then connect to me @KeLiuyue

Comment: I was in China .And It was at night at home.@Sushil

Comment: please bro if you have time then please get me in touch tommro because it is creating a lot of trouble for me

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
String response = "{date=29-07-2017,Reciept=RC1, Amount=11800}";
String responseConvert = response.replace("=", ":");
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<String> sIterator = null;
try {
    sIterator = new JSONObject(responseConvert).keys();
    while (sIterator.hasNext()) {
        // get key
        String key = sIterator.next();
        // get value
        String value = new JSONObject(responseConvert).getString(key);
        map.put(key, value);
        Log.e("TAG", "key: " + key + ",value：" + value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**

1. JSON data is illegal,so we must convert it.

   ```
   String responseConvert = response.replace("=", ":");
   ```
2. Use `Map<String,String>` and `Iterator<String>`

   ```
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   Iterator<String> sIterator = new JSONObject(responseConvert).keys();
   ```
3. Get key and value

   ```
   // get key
   String key = sIterator.next();
   // get value
   String value = new JSONObject(responseConvert).getString(key);
   ```

Comment: I added `try catch` in the code . You can check it.@Sushil